# React component don't recognize function?

Tags: reactjs, laravel-mix

I am fairly new in working with react.js. But I think with documentation everything should be possible, Right? Wrong.

Following documentation structure of a component I am trying to build a Filter Component. This is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class FilterBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      activeFilters: "",
      availableAttributes: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    $.ajax("/activeFilters", {
      success: function(e) {
        this.setActiveFilter(e);
      },

      error: function(e) {
        alert(e);
      }
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {}

  setActiveFilter(value) {
    this.setstate({
      activeFilters: value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="auto_banner" className="inline_block col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
        <div id="toggle_filterBody" className="text-left col-xs-5 col-md-2">
          <span>
            <img src="img/filter2.png" />
          </span>
          <span>Toggle Filter</span>
        </div>

        <div id="Quick_Filter">
          <h3>Smart Filter</h3>
          <p>
            Begin searching through hundreds of vehicles quickly with this easy
            to use tool.
          </p>

          <hr />

          <form name="quick_filter" encType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
            <div id="year_range">
              <span className="tag">Year Range</span>

              <div>
                <input
                  className="col-xs-5 year_range"
                  type="text"
                  name="min-year"
                  value=""
                  placeholder="MIN: yyyy"
                />
                to
                <input
                  className="col-xs-5 year_range"
                  type="text"
                  name="max-year"
                  value=""
                  placeholder="MAX: yyyy"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

if (document.getElementById("InventoryDisplay")) {
  ReactDOM.render(document.getElementById("FilterBar"));
  ReactDOM.render("ok", document.getElementById("InventoryDisplay"));
}
```

Now when I refresh the browser I get an error which says that the function  setActiveFilter  isn't recognized. Why?

Comment: I'd rather suggest you to use a HTTP library such as Axios or Request. Using jQuery just for AJAX is totally absurd, because you are already using React (both are UI libraries). It'll only make your project heavy.

Comment: Will look into it thanks for the input.  But does it make a difference if it is laravel mix?

Comment: any examples? @AjayGupta

Comment: I dont understand, what do you mean by "laravel mix" ?

Comment: @AjayGupta. I am using a mix of the laravel framework  and react.js....Jquery is an automatic dependency, because bootstrap requires it. But I wouldn't be against learning Axios or Request. Different Hammer for same nail bro.So point me in the direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `this` will reference an anonymous function not React Object you created:

```
$.ajax('/activeFilters',{    
    success: function(e){

        this.setActiveFilter(e);
    },

    error:function(e){
        alert(e);
    }
});
```

If you can use arrow functions try:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        activeFilters: '',
        availableAttributes:[]
    };

    this.setActiveFilter = this.setActiveFilter.bind(this); // this will make setActiveFilter be called with scope of your component object.
}

componentDidMount() {    
    $.ajax('/activeFilters',{    
        success: (e) => {    
            this.setActiveFilter(e);
        },

        error:function(e){
            alert(e);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yeah just tried that I before and copied and paste your answer still nothing I hate this at times...... Errors out of no where, should I screen shot the console errors?

Comment: @CalixteSimeon No, errors are text. The problem is your understanding of JS and the late binding of 'this'.

Comment: So. Ok cool I literally posted the entire file try and see if it runs. I don't know @DaveNewton everything but i know a little about OPP and  especially 'this'. I tried several variation and your example was one of the first.I am just stating my results.

Comment: TypeError: this.setActiveFilter is not a function[Learn More]
app.js:36286:21
success
http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:36286:21
fire
http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:6467:11
fireWith
http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:6597:7
done
http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:12504:5
callback/<
http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:12747:9

Comment: @CalixteSimeon I have modified the answer, did you tried it?

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk As far as I know, arrow functions don't create a scope and hence don't need bindings, right?

Comment: Yes. They do not have their own ‘this’ but use ‘this’ from context in which they are defined. Therefore they don’t need binding.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are calling **setActiveFilter** in global scope, not in the current component scope. Yo need to call function with current scope like:

> this.setActiveFilter(e);

in success callback of your ajax call written in `ComponentDidMount`

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work at all. console returns error 

TypeError: this.setActiveFilter is not a function[Learn More]
app.js:36286:21
success
http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:36286:21
fire
http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:6467:11
fireWith
http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:6597:7
done
http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:12504:5
callback/<
http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:12747:9

Comment: You need to bind the function in constructor.

this.setActiveFilter = this.setActiveFilter.bind(this)

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind it in Your constructor

```
this.setActiveFilter = this.setActiveFilter.bind(this);
```

I'm pretty sure that it will help ;)